# Where is PackageReference located in console application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have came across this line of code in a code and its quite confusing

One of my client send a dependancy  file that contains

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xyzrefrence" Version="1.3.0" />
```

and said it is console application. I created same kind of application but within packages.config
I found this thing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="xyz" version="1.7.7.7" targetFramework="net452" />
```

My question is that where the dependacy file located with the client setting(First settings)

Comment: Do you want to see the dependencies of the current nuget package by PackageReference format? In VS, it has two format(packages.config, PackageReference) to install nuget packages. In new sdk project(`standard`,`net core`), it only uses `PackageReference` nuget format which is a new management format. In the old sdk style project(net framework), you can use both of them.

Answer (score 1):

The reference (`<ItemGroup><PackageReference.....`) to the dependency can be 
found by editing the Visual Studio project file.  *.csproj

The dependency file itself can be found in your project's `/bin/debug` or `/bin/release` folders.

Comment: Thanks it not 100 right,  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan maybe I misunderstood.  The dependency files would be located in the `/bin/debug` or `/bin/release` folders beneath the project.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

> Where is PackageReference located in console application C#

There are two nuget mamangement format(`Packages.config` and `PackageReference`) to intall nuget packages.

**In fact**, [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) is a new nuget management format for new sdk projects(`net standard` and `net core`) since VS2017 while [Packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) is an old tranitional nuget management format for net framework projects.

**However**, you should **note** that for traditional framework projects, **Microsoft** made a concession to use the new SDK's pacakgeReference format, but there are still various compatibility issues.--------(`net frameowork` projects can use both of them while `net core`/`net standard` projects can only use **PackageReference**).

If you use a net framework project, you can change these two format before you install nuget packages at the beginning by **Tools**-->**Options**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**General**-->**Package Management**.

[image]

**And** you should specifiy this format before you install the first nuget package at the beginning and when you specify this format, the nugets you install later will use this method by default and cannot be changed.

> My question is that where the dependacy file located with the client
>   setting(First settings)

**1)** If you use a `net framework console` project with **PackageReference**, l am afraid that you cannnot see the depenencies of the nuget. The old sdk projects with PackageReference does not support showing the depenencies of the nuget packages due to several compatibility issues.

**2)** If you use a `net core console` project, you can see the dependencies in the Solution Explorer and the latest new sdk projects does support this. It has a new behavior that you can see every nuget package's depenencies under its branch in the Soluton Explorer.

[image]

**Besides**, since you use a framework project with `packages.config`, you can only see all of them(the premise is that this nuget package has dependencies.) in the `packages.config` file or in the `xxxx.csproj` file but it cannot subdivide dependencies for every nuget package.

**In additon**, if you still want to show the depenencies of the net framework projects with PackageReference, l suggest you could post a feature request in our [User Voice forum(DC)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)-`suggest a feature` to get Micorosft's attention.

Comment: And for PackgeReference,projects rerferences these packages directly under `C:\Users\user\.nuget` but for `packages.config`, projects reference the packages from the folder called packages under your solution(`packages.config` will copy these nuget packages from `.nuget` folder to `packages` folder under your solution). You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).